# Add an event listener on an objects property access/read

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to add an event listener to the access of a global object property? Not on the invocation of a function, but on actual reads of a property.

As an example, let's say I want to monitor all accesses to `window.screen`.

I don't want to change the existing behavior - `console.log(window.screen.availWidth)` should still work. However, I'd like to call another function upon that read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ES2015** has `Proxy` which has all sorts of weird and wonderful uses.

Given what you're asking:

> I want to monitor all accesses to window.screen.
>
> I don't want to change the existing behavior -
>   `console.log(window.screen.availWidth)` should still work. However, I'd
>   like to call another function upon that read.

**ES2015** `Proxy` sounds like the perfect tool.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
let handler = {

  get: (obj) => {
    
    console.log('I am the Proxy');
    return obj.availWidth;
  }
}

window.screen = new Proxy(window.screen, handler);

console.log(window.screen.availWidth);
```

---

**Further Reading:**

[A practical guide to Javascript Proxy](https://blog.bitsrc.io/a-practical-guide-to-es6-proxy-229079c3c2f0) is a good introduction to practical situations where `Proxy` comes in useful.

You'll find many more articles and tutorials across the web on **ES2015** `Proxy`.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Looks like exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of strange to do, but it's possible - if the property is configurable, you can change it to a getter/setter, where the getter invokes your own function, and then runs the original functionality.

`window.screen` is already a getter/setter, so first save a reference to the original getter/setter functions:

```js
const { get: origGet, set: origSet } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'screen');
Object.defineProperty(window, 'screen', {
  get() {
    console.log('Running custom code for window.screen getter!');
    return origGet.call(window);
  },
  set(param) {
    console.log('Running custom code for window.screen setter!');
    return origSet.call(window, param);
  }
});

console.log(window.screen);
```

(In this particular case, the built-in setter doesn't appear to actually do anything, though)